# Is there any difference between double strike and oubleday ikestray?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-joke-cards

The card [Atinlay Igpay](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Atinlay%20Igpay) has the ability oubleday ikestray. Is this functionally different from double strike?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a joke question.

Comment: I thought it was too, until I realized it was a joke *card*.  Unhinged is weird.  Still makes my head hurt to read this regardless.

Comment: When you say "functionally different", are you asking whether "oubleday ikestray" is the ability "double strike", or whether double string somehow functions differently when written in Pig Latin?

Comment: Unfortunately the [Unhinghed FAQ](http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/faq/unhinged) cover the Pig Latin part in detail, but don't address this! (My two cents: this is a board & card games site, not a pure-Magic-only site. Joke Magic is still a card game, and it's not the only silly card game out there, so why disallow it?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nop, it's the same.

Keep in mind, Atinlay Igpay is a card from the unhinged set. Meaning you can't normally play it except for casual play (and then usually you have to agree on it specifically).

The card is actually called Latin Pig in [Pig-latin](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pig%20latin) rules:

> Juvenile "code" language created by the rearrangement of sounds in a
> word such that the first sound is moved to the end and "ay" is added.
> In the case of a vowel as the first sound, "ay" is simply added, with
> an hyphen if necessary.

This is also how Double Strike turns into Oubleday Ikestray.

Comment: According to [MagicJudges.org](http://blogs.magicjudges.org/playerexperience/2015/10/08/chaos-draft-wacky-draft/) it is also allowed in certain limited formats.

Comment: @corsiKa Yep, and you even ignore ante text -- [[Contract from Below]] becomes ridiculous.

Answer (score 8):

**oNay, oubledayyay ikestrayyay isyay otnay onlyyay unctionallyfay identicalyay otay oubleDay ikeStray, ityay actuallyyay isyay oubleDay ikeStray**

atThay isyay ecausebay allyay exttay onyay ethay ardcay "igpayyay atinlayyay" isyay enderedray inyay [igPay atinLay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin), ichwhay ashay ellway-efinedday ulesray orfay itsyay eationcray. ereforeThay, otay akemay ethay ardcay eadableray, youyay avehay otay irstfay [onvertcay ityay](http://www.wordplays.com/pig-latin) ackbay otay egularray Englishyay

Comment: I managed to read it without any great difficulty, @murgatroid99. I found it helped to read it aloud as written.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Care to provide a source for that, since you're going all technical on me? All I could google was about non-English questions on stackoverflow, and BCG help center and meta also make no mention of official language that I could find.

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) is for all of Stack Exchange (excluding, of course, specifically non-English sites). I'll grant that most of the talk about this focuses on Stack Overflow, but that's clearly because it was written before the broader network existed.

Comment: @Hackworth The original trilogy (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User) has an official policy. The [question murgatroid linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/254466) contains not an official policy, but a strong recommendation with 209 upvotes and a whopping zero downvotes. That kind of unity is unheard of on meta. So yea, it isn't technically "official", but it may as well be.

Comment: illWay youyay alsoyay antgray atthay ethay ostpay youyay inkedlay isyay aboutyay uestionsqay, otnay answersyay?

Comment: -1. Questions about joke cards don't mean the answer should be a joke answer. Answering using Pig Latin is clearly a form of a joke. On a regular forum I would be upvoting this highly; but not on SE.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40285/134175) about why "English only" isn't explicitly mentioned in the FAQ.

Comment: Maybe providing a translation below would help make everyone happy?

Comment: @GendoIkari: Why not? [This answer on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is clearly a joke and has a net score of 4427 at the time of this comment.

Comment: Let's not get too worked up about this. Jokes in answers are usually fine as long as they don't get in the way of answering the question. Some people think this does ("unreadable"), some people are fine with it (it's +6/-2), so... goal should be to find the balance, not turn it into a big "Joke or Serious" argument.

Comment: Im upvoting cus its creative, must have took some time and its Funny! come on its a joke guys regardless of the sites "Laws". Some people that play this game are serious enough without all the hate for joke answers.

Answer (score 6):

Just as "Doppelschlag", "Doppio attacco", "Golpe duplo", and many others; "Oubleday ikestray" is just a regular "Double Strike" on a non-english card.

Comment: Very much +1, but a pointer to the relevant part of the [Unhinged FAQTIWDAWCC](http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/faq/unhinged) (_"This question actually caused quite a debate here in R&D."_) would be a nice addition.